# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to europewest.services.azureml.net:443 (with RCurl)

Tags: r, rcurl

calling request (Request/Response, not Batch execution, Azure Machine Learning Web service) fails. Error is in topic, I have updated RCurl-library to solve problem, but it wasn't.

Request R-code is taken from the "Request Response API Documentation for XXXXX".

This R-code worked fine until January 2020 (worked about 2 years).

What to try next?

Comment: hi LL84, I recently had a similar issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

An R script to contact webservices deployed with Azure ML is available at the following link

https://studio.azureml.net/apihelp/workspaces/26d0e94d818b46c099320b38c0495493/webservices/ba6fb51adb48479dbda75cff0fd2c05a/endpoints/92c6c73f1dbc4c0baf57b075d6ea7f50/score

The "RCurl" library is deprecated for contacting Azure ML webservices. In contrary the "curl" and "httr" R libraries should be used.